# What is Responsive Side Navigation?

Tags: support, reputation

I got this **Responsive Side Navigation** in my profile page in reputation. For this i got -2 reputation. I don't have any link on this. Look below image. I don't know what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the title of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600091/responsive-side-navigation) you submitted a suggested edit on at one point. Your edit was approved and you got 2 reputation for it.

The question was deleted by the author yesterday, so the reputation you got for editing it was removed as well. It doesn't show up as a link in your profile since you don't yet have [enough reputation to view other people's deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).